# Add a text field to a form- populate it with a 'default value' using Python/Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am working on a Python/Django project, and one of the fields on a form is currently broken (it's a `datetimepicker` field- the issue is that you can't select dates beyond 01/01/2017). It seems this is because the library being used to add the `datetimepicker` is no longer supported).

I will look into implementing a `datetimepicker` myself, but need to allow the user to select dates beyond the 01/01/2017 on this form- in order to save the dates and times for scheduled meetings, etc.

My thoughts for the moment are to create a temporary fix, by adding simple `EasyText` fields to the form for the date/ time. I am aware that this means that the data entered will not be validated, so there is room for user input error, but it will enable the user to set dates/ times for meeting at least temporarily, until I fix the issue with the current `datetimepicker` field.

The form that I want to add these fields to is defined in forms.py with:

```
class PostDepMeetingForm(ValidatedForm):
    postdep_meeting_date = MoonDateTimeField(required=False, widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', attrs=({'class':'datetimepicker'})))
    planning_who = forms.CharField(required=False)
    general_notes = EasyText(label='Survey notes')
    #ERF(16/12/2016 @ 1345) Add a text area for the meeting date & time
meeting_date_time = EasyText(label='Meeting date & time')

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = ('postdep_meeting_date', 'planning_who','building_regs','general_notes', 'meeting_date_time')


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', {})
        project = instance.project

        try:
            postdep_meeting = project.meetings.get(purpose=3)
            self.postdep_meeting_id = postdep_meeting.id
            self.postdep_meeting_creator = postdep_meeting.event_creator or ''
            postdep_meeting_date = postdep_meeting.date
            general_notes = postdep_meeting.notes
            #ERF(16/12/2016 @ 1420) Try setting the meeting_date_time EasyText's default value to postdep_meeting.date & postdep_meeting.time
            #meeting_date_time

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            postdep_meeting_date = None
            general_notes = None

        try: planning_who = project.assigned.select_related('employee').get(role=Role.PL).employee.id
        except ObjectDoesNotExist: planning_who = None

        initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
        initial={
                'postdep_meeting_date': postdep_meeting_date,
                'general_notes': general_notes,
                'planning_who': planning_who,
                }
        kwargs['initial'] = initial

        super(PostDepMeetingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['planning_who'] = AutoFlexiSelect(model='e', choices=get_choices('ARCHITECT_CHOICES') + [('*', 'Other')], label="Who", current_id=planning_who,)
        self.fields['postdep_meeting_date'].widget.attrs.update({'data-meeting-id': getattr(self,'postdep_meeting_id', ''), 'data-meeting-creator': getattr(self,'postdep_meeting_id', '')})

    def save(self, commit=True):
        project = self.instance.project
        data = self.cleaned_data

        if 'postdep_meeting_date' in self.changed_data:
            postdep_meeting = Meeting.objects.get_or_create(project=project, purpose=3)[0]
            postdep_meeting.date = data['postdep_meeting_date']
            postdep_meeting.notes = data['general_notes']
            postdep_meeting.save()

        if data['planning_who']:
            try: project.assigned.select_related('employee').get(role=Role.PL).delete()
            except ObjectDoesNotExist: pass
            pe = ProjectEmployee.objects.create(role=Role.PL, project=project, employee_id=data['planning_who'])

        return super(PostDepMeetingForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

I have added the `EasyText` field, called `meeting_date_time` to the form, and can see it displayed on the form when I view the page in the browser.

What I'm unsure about how to do now- is save any input entered by the user, and have whatever they have input into that field displayed there automatically the next time they browse to that page... Will I need to add a new field to the `project` model to save this information?

**Edit**

As requested in a comment, `ValidatedForm` is defined with:

```
class ValidatedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_css_class = 'error-field'
    required_css_class = 'required'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ValidatedForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # for k, field in self.fields.items():
        #   if 'required' in field.error_messages:
        #       # print 'field error', field, field
        #       # field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'error-field'
        #       print 'field error', k
        #       field.error_messages['required'] = '*'
        #   else:
        #       print 'Field erroR', field
```

and `EasyText` is a 'text area' for storing user input on the form, defined with:

```
def EasyText(field_class="medium", readonly=False, placeholder='', extras={}, **kwargs):
    textarea = forms.CharField(widget=TextareaWidget(attrs={'class':field_class, 'readonly':readonly, 'placeholder': placeholder}))
    if extras:
        textarea.widget.attrs.update(**extras)

    try: textarea.label = kwargs['label']
    except KeyError: pass
    try: textarea.required = kwargs['required']
    except KeyError: textarea.required = False
    return textarea
```

Comment: You'll need to explain what ValidatedForm and EasyText are, and why you would think a new field would not be validated.

Comment: If you want to disable the JavaScript date picker, then try removing the `attrs=({'class':'datetimepicker'})` from the field. Disabling the datepicker seems like a better work-around than creating additional fields.

Comment: I've added the definitions of `ValidatedForm` & `EasyText`. When I say the new field would not be validated- I mean it would not format the input as a date/ time, it would just store text... Since the field currently being used is a `datetimepicker`, obviously the data saved through this part of the form has a specific `datetime` format.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks @Alasdair , so I could remove the `attribute` from the field, and this would just make it a normal `textfield`- with any input being stored as text?

Comment: The field type would stay the same in Django. Removing the class means that it won't be rendered with `class='datetimepicker'` in the CSS. That means that the datepicker would stop working on that field (assuming your datepicker javascript library only works on inputs with that class).